# Firestore DocumentSnapshot.data() returns undefined, but in the console it definetly has and it works for other documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In this Firebase Function I'm getting two DocumentSnapshots, the first works fine, I can get the data (emailNonce) from the db, but the second DocumentSnapshot somehow has no data, the object is there, I can see it in the logs, but calling .data() on it returns undefined:

```
    const addRentalFct = async (data, context) => {

    // this works:
    const secretsRef = db.collection('user-secrets').doc('Yv3gZU8TeJTixl0njm7kUXXpvhc2');
    const secretsSnap = await secretsRef.get();
    const dbNonce = secretsSnap.data().emailNonce;
functions.logger.log('got the dbNonce: ', dbNonce);

    // this doesn't work, but ir's the same logic as above:
    const boxesSecretsRef = db.collection('box-secrets').doc('CB8lNQ8ZUnv4FDT6ZXGW');
    const boxSecretsSnap = await boxesSecretsRef.get();
    functions.logger.log('got the boxSecretsSnap: ', boxSecretsSnap);
    functions.logger.log('got the boxSecretsSnap.data(): ', boxSecretsSnap.data());
    const boxPassword = boxSecretsSnap.data().password;
    functions.logger.log('the box secret is: ', boxPassword);

...
}
```

[image: logs]

The DB:
box-secrets collection
[image: box-secrets]

user-secrets:
[image: user-secrets]

(the secrets are from my dev environment)

Comment: My first guess would be that there is a non-printable character in the ID of the document in `box-secrets`. If you `console.log(boxSecretsSnap.exists)`, what does it output? If that is false, you might want to get all documents from `box-secrets` and log their IDs to see if that shows any difference.

Comment: Thanks, for exists it says: `Unhandled error TypeError: boxSecretsSnap.exists is not a function at addRentalFct`, bc it couldnt find the doc at all, but I found the error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I copied the id for the new document from an already existing document in the console like this:
[image: copied from here]

Automatically there was a space added in front. When I created the new doc, the space was not visible, but I could create another doc with the same id, without the space in front. Here you see that it
s not that obvious, it looks like there are two docs with the exact same id:
[image: space is not visible]
When having it like this, the firebase function didn't find any of the two docs. I had delete both and readd it without space, then it worked.